# Does multi-layer inheritance make sense in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I use 3-layer inheritance design below:

```
class connect_info {
  // these members
};

class vertex : public connect_info {
  // ...
};

// user-defined struct
class algo_vertex: public vertex {
  // ...
};
```

members of `connect_info` class(I call it `these members` in this question) is only used in `vertex` class. But to keep the semantic of `vertex` class clear, I must separate `these members` to another base class(`connect_info`).

Problems generate here:

1. how can I hide these members from user-defined class? (`protected` and `private` are both useless now. If there is no `connect_info` base class, `private` can work well)
2. Does multi-layer inheritance design make sense in any situation?
3. Can virtual de-constructor function work well in multi-layer inheritance case?

Comment: 1) then don't inherit publicly 2) certainly

Comment: do not use `private` inheritance. Make things simpler. Again, this depends on how you want to structure your code.

Answer (score 5):

You might need to move to `has-a` relationship, where `connect_info` can be an internal `class`(A class inside class) and make it `private`, if you want to hide `connect_info` members in `user defined class`.

```
class vertex {
  // ...
  private:
     class connect_info{/*these members*/};
};

class algo_vertex : public vertex{ 
  // connect_info members no longer accessible,
  // unless you provide member functions in `vertex` to access it.
};
```

Comment: What is the difference between internal class and privately inheritance in this case?

Comment: Keeping things simple is the idea here @xunzhang, you have more control over who gets to use what in `connect_info` class.

Comment: @xunzhang the difference is also a semantic one (which seemed to be your interest if I read your question correctly) : Does a vertex have a connect_info member or is a vertex a specialized version of a connect_info ?
Do not use inheritance when "A is a special version of B" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Aniket with internal class, how can I use these members?

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is introducing strong coupling between classes, and is generally avoided. Instead, people are using composition. Read [Prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) question and answers.

In your specific example, what do you do, when you add `algo_B_vertex` class, where some of fields and methods from `Vertex` make no sense. Or in worse case scenario `connect_info`. Then you get into all sorts of problems. Not to mention complexity of several layers of inheritance.

> how can I hide these members from user-defined class?

By using composition, and creating objects in private section.

> Does multi-layer inheritance design make sense in any situation?

Of course it does. Fortunately that number of such situations is little. General advice is to think twice before jumping into multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

A good trade-of here would be to make `vertex`inherit privately from `connect_info`. The big difference with composition is that within the class `vertex` you can consider yourself being a `connect_info`, which means you will be able to access `these members` by doing `this->member` instead of `connect_info_attribute.member`. Also you won't need any `friend` or encapsulation hacks.

To sum it up, from the point of view of the child class, `private` inheritance means i consider myself being a "parent" but i don't want anyone else (not even my children) to consider me like one.